# How to Count occurrence of a specific character in a specific position of string - MYSQL 5.5

Tags: mysql, subquery, mysql-5.5

I have this type of data in a column:

```
!-------!---!-------
!-------!-----!-----
!-------!!----------
!-------!-----!-----
!-------!-----!-----
```

I need to count the occurrence of '!' - in EACH position of the string.

For position 1 - I should get a count of 5,
position 2 - 0
position 3 - 0
position 4 - 0
position 5 - 0
position 6 - 0
position 7 - 0
position 8 - 0
position 9 - 5 
So on and so on. There's 20 positions. I want to ignore the '-'.

I have tried to use locate:

```
select 
        `color` AS `color`,
        locate('!',
                `Info`) AS `Position`,
        count(`Info`) AS `Count`
    from
        `CountReport`
    where
        (locate('!',
                `Info`) = 1)
    group by `color`
```

But if the '!' shows up in the first position every time it doesn't count the other instances of the character. I have a script for each position.

ANY help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much in advance!

~h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure whether it's the most efficient way to do this:

```
select count(case substring(s,1,1) when '!' then 1 else NULL end) as pos1,
       ...
       count(case substring(s,10,1) when '!' then 1 else NULL end) as pos10,
       ...
       count(case substring(s,20,1) when '!' then 1 else NULL end) as pos20
from test;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c44767/6)

Comment: You know... I think that's going to work! You're a genius! :D Thanks so much!!